# jquery unbind function event once executed

Tags: jquery, function, bind, unbind, die

**Hi Folks,**
Please help me to fix this : Suppose we call the same javascript function from anchors but with different parameter

```
<a id="edit1" onclick="foo(1)"></a> 
<a id="edit2" onclick="foo(2)"></a>

function foo(id)
{
// let's say the code here hide the clicked anchor and show a new anchor with cancel-edit id 
}
```

The scenario :

- I clicked in the first anchor - The first anchor replaced with a new anchor :
- **How can i disable the function, so when i click in  the second anchor it does nothng.**
- Now suppose i clicked in the anchor with the id cancel-edit  it will pull back the anchor with the id edit1 and reactivate the foo function so when i reclick in the second anchor it will execute again the foo function...

i hope it's clear :X ! 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable it for all the elements after one is clicked, you could just set a flag:

```
var enabled = true;
function foo(id) {
    if( enabled ) {
        // run your code
        enabled = false;
    }
}
```

It will continue to run, but the code in the `if` statement will not after the first click.

```
function stop() {

    // replace the original anchor

    enabled = true; // enable the "foo" handler

}
```

When the new anchor with `stop()` is clicked, you replace it with the original anchor, and set `enabled` to `true` so that `foo()` will work again.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! sorry but ihavnt explained very well what i want to do. This is the scenario :

Comment: - I clicked in the first anchor 
- The first anchor replaced with a new anchor : <a onclick="stop()"></> 
- Now when i click in the second anchor it does nothing 
- But when i click in the new anchor which call the javascript stop function, it does reactivate the foo function 
- And when i reclick in the second anchor, it will work 
Sorry for my bad english i trying my best :)!

Comment: @v1r00z: You'll need to edit your question, and add more code and details.

Comment: @v1r00z: I updated my answer. Just have your `stop()` function set `enabled = true` so that `foo` will work again.